# Extracting sub-string of 4 digit in a line

Tags: regex, boost-regex

Trying to figure out how to extract groups of 4 digit using regex

The regex I'm using now :

```
regex_time : "(([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9])";
```

Code sample:

```
regex expressionFormat(REGEX_TIME);
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;

if (boost::regex_search(input,what,expressionFormat))
```

My input would usually be in the form of

`"0000 1800 2359"`

And I would like to push them into a vector to do some comparsion.

It's for parsing time in string format from a line.

Comment: Just split the input by space.

Comment: Are you trying to perform some validation on the input as well?  If not, you would not need regular expressions...

Comment: there might be other stuffs in it, for etc

"add 0000 2359"

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do some validation. I'm only grabbing time in 24hrs clock

Comment: Your regex for 24-hour time looks okay...  Can you post what the results are from executing your code?  i.e. is your `regex_search` falling through the `if` or are the values not what you expect?

Comment: It's not failing. It's only returning the first match. The issue might lie in the regex_search function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `while` loop instead of `if` for `regex_search`:

```
string input;
boost::regex regex("(([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9])");
boost smatch;

while (boost::regex_search(input.start(), input.end(), what, regex)) {
    // what[0] contains current full match
    // what[2] contains the hours
}
```

Note that each loop will move `what` to the next value.  See the example on the boost doc page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html

The values of indices in `what` are determined by your capture groups in the expression.  If you wanted to create another group to match minutes, simply create a new group:

```
"(([01][0-9]|2[0-3])([0-5][0-9]))"
```

To determine the group index in `what`, count forward the number of open parenthesis.